# How to add CSRF protection to AJAX call on Symfony3?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, csrf

I'm developing a web where you can 'add friend' another user, like facebook does. For now, I put a link, and when you click on it, an AJAX call is done.

Before persist the new friendship, I check if request is Ajax, but I want to go further and add more security. A page can have more than 10 links (posible requests), so... I don't know if I need only one token, or a token per link.

Another doubt is.... How to generate a token and check if is valid using Symfony? Focused on how generate the token on the initial controller, and then, how to validate on the addFriend controller (that receive the ajax call).

I tried to use this to generate a token:

http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Security/Csrf/TokenGenerator/TokenGeneratorInterface.html

And then this to check the token:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/csrf_token_validation.html

But always return that the token is **not** valid.

Comment: Create the form as a normal Symfony form, then load it into your template and send the form via ajax. It will have the CSRF token like any other Symfony form

Comment: Thanks, but seems for me a bad practice to create a form for no form elements.

Comment: It will have an element - the CSRF token. It will maybe have other hidden fields. It's not bad practice, it is using Symfony framework in the way it is intended

Comment: Just make sure to generate the token by using the same `'token_id'` used to validate it.

Comment: If you're in twig context you can use `{{ csrf_token('token_id') }}`

Comment: @yceruto I found this thanks to your comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#csrf-token I will try it and post an update.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally I find a workaround for my problem.

As @yceruto commented, is possible to generate a `csrf token` without any form, see this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#csrf-token

With this, I can create my links on TWIG on the following way:

```
<a data-id="{{ user.id }}" class="card-link clickable sendFriendRequest" data-token="{{ csrf_token(user.id) }}">ADD_FRIEND</a>
```

Then, I do an AJAX call like this:

```
$('.elementsList').on('click','.sendFriendRequest', function () {

var userId = $(this).data('id');
var token = $(this).data('token');

$.post('/users/sendFriendRequest/'+userId, {token: token}
).done(function (response) {
    //Some code here

}).fail(function (response) {


});

});
```

Finally, you check if the token is valid on your contoller using the following code:

```
$token = $request->request->get('token');

$isValidToken = $this->isCsrfTokenValid($townId, $token);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the `$townId`? Wouldnt that be the user ID that was used to generate the token?

Comment: @Chris I don't know why he added `$townId`, you just have to add the identifier of the token as the first parameter of the function. So if you create your token like this `csrf_token('foobar')` then you can check its validity like this: `$this->isCsrfTokenValid('foobar', $token)`

Comment: Sorry @Chris, I added the object ID because I have a list of objects, so I want to have different tokens for each object... It's only to improve the security.